# Is there a way to count the number of seconds since bootup?

Tags: c#, .net, seconds

Is there a way to count the number of seconds(ticks?) since bootup even if a user change the time on computer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`System.Environment.TickCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx) is what you want. It gets the number of milliseconds since the system was started.